# Interface Activity and Adapter

Tags: android, android-activity, interface, android-recyclerview

I want to send 0/1 to my adapter from my activity. This is my code :

OnActivityButtonClickedListener :

```
public interface OnActivityButtonClickedListener {
    public void OnActivityButtonClicked(int id);
}
```

Main Activity :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    private TabLayout mainTabLayout;
    private ViewPager mainViewPager;
    private OnActivityButtonClickedListener mListener = sDummyCallbacks;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mainTabLayout = findViewById(R.id.MainTabLayout);
        mainViewPager = findViewById(R.id.MainViewPager);
        MainViewPagerAdapter adapter = new MainViewPagerAdapter(this, getSupportFragmentManager());
        mainViewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        MainActionModeSelectAll = findViewById(R.id.MainActionModeSelectAll);
        MainActionModeCancel = findViewById(R.id.MainActionModeCancel);

        MainActionModeSelectAll.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mListener.OnActivityButtonClicked(0);
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "mListener got 0", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        MainActionModeCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mListener.OnActivityButtonClicked(1);
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "mListener got 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    private static OnActivityButtonClickedListener sDummyCallbacks = new OnActivityButtonClickedListener() {
        @Override
        public void OnActivityButtonClicked(int id) {
        }
    };

}
```

Adapter :

```
public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.ViewHolder> implements OnActivityButtonClickedListener {
    @Override
    public void OnActivityButtonClicked(int id) {
        switch (id) {
            case 0:
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "0" ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //do something
                break;
            case 1:
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "1" ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //do something else
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

adapter is inside a fragment inside activity.
i can see toasts on activity yet toasts on adapter are not shown. any idea what is the problem?

Comment: Please post your code properly next time or at least code it properly. And if you want to send something from an Activity to an Adapter, create a method that takes "something" as its argument in the Adapter. Then have the activity keep an instance of Adapter. No need interface here.

Comment: @HauLuu more code added. Since my adapter is inside fragment i need interface. thanks for your time.

Comment: Okay,

Step 1: Define an interface (IA) inside the Fragment that host the Adapter

Step 2: Make the Activity that host the Fragment implements this (IA) interface

Step 3: Trigger the interface (IA) when needed.

Then Fragment will get notify when the Activity trigger the interface and the Fragment could send data to the Adapter because it has referenced to it.

Answer (score 0):

Man! you need to check this link

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating#DefineInterface

Define an Interface in the Fragment that hosts your Adapter then the Fragment will send the data from the Activity to the Adapter for you.